# Using ComponentQuery to find a certain Component - extjs

Tags: extjs, controls, panel, init

I'm using a controller to initialize a function when a certain panel is rendered. How can i use the ComponentQuery to detect the exact panel without using 'parent > child' finders?

Here's the code:

```
Ext.define('MC.controller.Description', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
    init: function() {
        this.control({
            '**what goes here?**': {
                render: this.onPanelRendered
            }
        });
    },

    onPanelRendered: function() {
        console.log('PANEL WAS RENDERED WHOOO');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `itemId` and then do lookups using `queryById`